# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined" on autoplay.stop() (Swiper)

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

I've initialized two Swiper instances in a Wordpress setup. The slideshows in their self are working as expected, but I'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stop' of undefined` in the console when trying to stop the autoplay of one of the slideshows when hovering.

The setup in my Javascript looks like this:

```
var newsSwiper = new Swiper ('.s2', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 20,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 5000,
    },
  });

  var filmSwiper = new Swiper ('.s1', {
    // Optional parameters
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    spaceBetween: 20,

    // Navigation arrows
    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
  });

  jQuery(".s2").hover(function() {
    newsSwiper.autoplay.stop();
  });
```

After reading some [issues](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/191#issuecomment-341513406) on Swiper's Github, this seems to be the correct way of doing it. But for some reason the function doesn't recognize the `newsSwiper` variable. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem shortly after. The problem was in the markup, where I accidentally had the same class (`.s2`) on both slideshows. Changing it so that only one of the slideshow has the class `.s2` made the error go away.